# How to load MySql Table image (BLOB ) in to ImageView using JDBC Drive

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview

I have a project working on. in this project I am trying to get login user image in to ImageView from MySQL table via JDBC Driver, in this case, image is loading one time and second time if I try to load the picture then system is giving an error, after the error again if I try to load the image then image is loading in to the ImageView. Here I am attaching the code.

```
private class findpicture extends  AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String msg;
    String searchtext= textView3.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Searching username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        textView3.setText("");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);

            if (con == null){
                msg="Connection error...";
            }else{
                byte b[];
                Blob blob;
                Statement statement= (Statement) con.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from userlogin where name='"+searchtext+"'");

                while (resultSet.next()){
                    blob = resultSet.getBlob("image");
                    b= blob.getBytes(1, (int)blob.length());
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
                    savedphoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                msg= "user image saved successfully...";

            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            msg="unknown error..."+e;

            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

> Error Code  android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException:
>   Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `Thread` conflict you need to recheck your calls and synchronized tasks there,
Quick fix to your issue

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new findpicture().execute();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I have seen may solution like this but I don't know how to apply this code into my project.

Comment: I updated my answer, just wrap the `new findpicture().execute();` using the `runOnUiThread`

Comment: Thank you, I update the code as you say, but the issue is still the same.

Comment: I update the thread into OnPost Execute then the image is loading properly.